# Cannot connect to wireless Bluetooth speaker, Ubuntu LTS 18.04

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth, blueman

The Bluetooth speaker is visible as a device from my laptop, however if I try to connect to the device through the Bluetooth GUI interface nothing happens. All it does is say "Not Set Up" next to the device prior to and following (after a short loading delay) my attempt to connect.

I have also tried connecting using bluetoothctl from the terminal. This, also, does not work, however it seems to suggest that my laptop *is*, in fact, able to connect to the speaker, but this connection is simply dropped after a second or two. Below is a screenshot of the output when I try to connect to the speaker through terminal (ignore the first failed pairing attempt, as the speaker had turned itself off after a period of inactivity):

[terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJdrd.png)

I am able to connect to the speakers with my phone, as well as my Windows 10 OS (dual-boot), thus it seems to be a problem with Ubuntu.

I have also tried using blueman to connect to the speakers, however this also gives an error, a screenshot of which is again linked below:

[blueman output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8yvr.png)

The model of the speaker is a Harman Kardon Onyx Studio 2, if that's of any use.

Comment: With the same device see no issues here though.. Occasionally need to open  Bluetooth Settings ( the default one, not blueman) > highlight & remove HK Onyx Studio device, close Settings. Then turn on speaker, open Bluetooth Settings again & add it back, ect.

Comment: @doug just tried that but doesn't seem to help (i presume you mean the "Bluetooth Devices" GUI menu, the one reached from Settings doesn't allow you to remove devices or anything like that). it just does the same thing that trying to connect from terminal did; it connects for like half a second then just drops the connection. interestingly it looks like it also can no longer *see* the device when the connection is dropped (disappears from the list of seen devices) until it connects again only to lose connection. although now it seems unable to see the device at all, so by this point idk :/

Comment: I use unity in 18.04, it makes things much easier. Anyway try opening System Settings > Bluetooth. You should see your device listed in a box, double click on the entry, a small window should pop up that lets you remove the device.